# Why aren't my start() and stop() methods working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

Why aren't my start() and stop() methods working? I can't get to pause and play the audio, Can someone see anything wrong that I'm doing?

In js fiddle `$` is replaced with `jQuery`

So moving on This is what my code is, I've used:

```
            $('.play').click(function() {
                audioBufferSouceNode.start();   
            });

            $('.pause').click(function() {
                audioBufferSouceNode.stop();
            });

            $('.volumeMax').click(function() {
                audioBufferSouceNode.volume=1;
            });

            $('.volumestop').click(function() {
                audioBufferSouceNode.volume=0;
            });

            $('.playatTime').click(function() {
                audioBufferSouceNode.currentTime= 35;
                audioBufferSouceNode.play();
            });
```

but for some reason it's not working. this is my index.php page.

```
           <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="fileWrapper" class="file_wrapper">
            <div id="info">
                HTML5 Audio API showcase | An Audio Viusalizer
            </div>
            <label for="uploadedFile">Drag&drop or select a file to play:</label>
            <input type="file" id="uploadedFile"></input>
        </div>
        <div id="visualizer_wrapper">
            <canvas id='canvas' width="800" height="350"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
   <div class="audioPlayer">  

        <button type="button" class="play">play</button>
        <button type="button" class="pause">pause</button>
        <button type="button" class="playatTime">play at 35 seconds</button>
        <button type="button" class="volumestop">Volume to 0</button>
        <button type="button" class="volumeMax">Volume open</button>
```

This is where my buttons are being used in the javascript file, which is on line 134 on the code: https://jsfiddle.net/4hty6kak/16/

```
   _visualize: function(audioContext, buffer) {
    audioBufferSouceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource(),
        analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser(),
        that = this;
    //connect the source to the analyser
    audioBufferSouceNode.connect(analyser);

            jQuery('.play').click(function() {
                audioBufferSouceNode.start();   
            });

            jQuery('.pause').click(function() {
                audioBufferSouceNode.stop();
            });

            jQuery('.volumeMax').click(function() {
                audioBufferSouceNode.volume=1;
            });

            jQuery('.volumestop').click(function() {
            audioBufferSouceNode.volume=0;
            });

            jQuery('.playatTime').click(function() {
                audioBufferSouceNode.currentTime= 35;
                audioBufferSouceNode.play();
            }); 



    //connect the analyser to the destination(the speaker), or we won't hear the sound
    analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);
    //then assign the buffer to the buffer source node
    audioBufferSouceNode.buffer = buffer;
    //play the source
    if (!audioBufferSouceNode.start) {
        audioBufferSouceNode.start = audioBufferSouceNode.noteOn //in old browsers use noteOn method
        audioBufferSouceNode.stop = audioBufferSouceNode.noteOff //in old browsers use noteOn method
    };
    //stop the previous sound if any
    if (this.animationId !== null) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.animationId);
    }
    if (this.source !== null) {
        this.source.stop(0);
    }
    audioBufferSouceNode.start(0);
    this.status = 1;
    this.source = audioBufferSouceNode;
    audioBufferSouceNode.onended = function() {
        that._audioEnd(that);
    };
    this._updateInfo('Playing ' + this.fileName, false);
    this.info = 'Playing ' + this.fileName;
    document.getElementById('fileWrapper').style.opacity = 0.2;
    this._drawSpectrum(analyser);
 },
```

full code:

https://jsfiddle.net/4hty6kak/16/

I've tried using

```
audioBufferSouceNode.source.start();
```

&

```
audioBufferSouceNode.source.stop();
```

instead but still doesn't work! 
Do you have any solutions? At this rate, I don't care what solutions you have, even if it's using jQuery. Something straightforward and an easy fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `start` once on `audioBufferSourceNode`, and in general to most sources nodes of the `web audio API`. See http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-AudioBufferSourceNode-start-void-double-when-double-offset-double-duration

> start may only be called one time

So if ou want these behaviors you'll need to change your logic quite a bit, meaning you have to recreate the node on start. I made a barely working version, it's just to show how you could work, but as I said it requires a somewhat important refactoring of your code if you want it to work.
But basically, you should have a start method that creates the audio node and do the connections. In your case `_visualize` is not too far, so in the example I called `_visualize` on start. But obviously it causes other problem such as the click events. 
And you have to see which objects you'll need to recycle, you can keep some (`analyser` for example), but some not, so you'll have to sort that out also.

```
    _visualize: function (audioContext, buffer) {
        audioBufferSouceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();


        that = this;
        //connect the source to the analyser
        audioBufferSouceNode.connect(analyser);

        jQuery('.play').click(function () {
            audioContext.decodeAudioData(fileResult, function (buffer) {
                that._updateInfo('Decode succussfully,start the visualizer', true);
                that._visualize(audioContext, buffer);
            }, function (e) {
                that._updateInfo('!Fail to decode the file', false);
                console.log(e);
            });

        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h3yvp0zw/4/

Again, it's just an example, it's not working well, after a few clicks the visualiser drops for some reason, probably too many click events. It's just to show where the problem is.

EDIT:

Maybe a better a approach would be to use `mediaElementSourceNode` instead of `audioBufferSourceNode`. `mediaElementSourceNode` allows to feed a regular `HTML Audio Element` into a context and so apply effects and/or analyser. This allows to use regular controls of the `HTML Audio element` such as play and pause.

IT works that way:

First create an audio element.

```
var audioElement = new Audio('sourcefile');
```

Then your `mediaElementSource` refering to your element:

```
var source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
```

Then `connect` it to your `analyser`:

```
source.connect(analyser);
```

And apply your behaviors to your element:

```
audioElement.play();
audioElement.pause();
```

etc.

Note that while audio element can work with cross domain files, it's not the case with `mediaElementSource`. The security is different, if you use a cross domain file on an audio element, the audio element might play, but once you feed it to mediaSourceElement, it'll stop, it'll just output silence.

This means you'd need to modify the way the files are handled, you'll probably need to put them on server and then feed the path to your audio element.

Comment: No buffer nodes don't have play method. You could if you were using createMediaElementSource instead of buffer, in that case your source can be a regular html audio element and you control play and pause as you do with audio html elements. But the fact that you're asking for a file from the user makes it more complicated. Not sure it's possible without some server intervention.

Comment: im pretty much trying to create audio controls, the thing is I don't know how to rearrange the code in terms of creating the node of the start. Since im not that great at javascript! hmm, I guess I'll have to ask that as another question?

Comment: Except for testing and learning, I don't think buffer node is suited to play audio files with controls the way you have it set up. If you look at the specs it's mainly to play short sounds, sound effects for example, or background loops that sort of things. Your setup would work much better with mediaElement. You should start with that, using files on your server. Or maybe someone else will come up with an easy solution... I may have overlook some ways to make it work easily.

Comment: so is it possible to save the files on the server and then its grabs the file that way and then plays it with audio controls AND visualizer?? how would I go about doing that? If I "ask" that as question would you be able to show me how? obviously I know how to store the file on the server, but what would I do with that file from the server? How would I implement it exactly?

Comment: Okay thank you for your edit, making perfect sense now, I'm going to be working towards this, this entire week. Just to clarify, If I create a table in mysql, lets say its called musicTable where the music files gets stored. Then I can feed the path of those music files stored on the database table to the audio element, it will work that way right? Is that what you mean? Just clarifying, thanks